# For loop for txt files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to add one particular line at the beginning in a directory of txt files in each and every file. Following is the code I am using :

```
For %%f in (*.txt) do
echo "Computer String : %%f" > newFile.txt
type %%f >> newFile.txt
type newFile.txt > %%f
```

However, as soon as I execute this, no change is observed. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You are missing the parentheses.  You need one after the `DO` and then one at the end to close the code block.  [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3695/for-loops-in-batch-files/12893/renaming-all-files-in-the-current-directory#t=20170308190416716818)

Comment: First step in troubleshooting a batch file is to execute the batch file from the command prompt instead of double clicking it with your mouse.  If you would have done that you would have seen this on your screen right after the FOR command executed. **The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

Comment: I'd also recommend not writing to a `.txt` file in the same directory you are reading `.txt` files from.

Comment: Thanks Squashman.... parenthesis got it working !! :)